# Is an answer to a different question still an answer?

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42010098/2333545) answer as not an answer because it wasn't answering the actual question that was asked. The flag was declined for "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer."

I still think this isn't an answer because it's not addressing the question posed, but instead a similar, related issue. Does this count as an answer or not?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer  but doesn't directly answer your question, which is when the author actually isn't trying to answer the question asked. My understanding is that as long as it looks like it's trying to answer *a* question, that flag shouldn't be used.

Comment: Was it a good-faith attempt to answer a question? Then don't flag. If it's a bad answer, or doesn't answer the actual question, downvote it. Only flag if it's obviously not even an attempt to answer a question.

Comment: To clarify: when we say "a" question instead of "the" question, we mean "does it look like it could be an answer to a question on this site" not the specific question it was on. On another note, it's interesting that the main Meta site and Stack Overflow's meta disagree on whether link only answers can be flagged as NAA.

Comment: @BSMP any link only answer can be flagged as NAA if it is truly a link only answer (some people say only the VLQ flag applies but that's poppycock). The really big thing is that you have to strip the link markup, then evaluate the answer. If the answer suggests a possible solution after the link markup is removed, then it is an answer.

Comment: If an answer is an answer it is an answer.